# How to constrain rotation between 2 angles in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object which is able to rotate, two of the axes of rotation as shown in the editor will always be zero, the other is a constrained variable.

[image]

I have found that `transform.rotation.eulerAngles` yields some success and finding and modifying this value, but I do not understand it's behaviour. It can repeatedly go between 0-90 in different quadrants and more.

Here is my current attempt:

```cs
// rotationParent is the object that is rotating
// offset is a constant offset that the object is rotated by
// constraintRange is a vector of the form Vector2(min, max)

// Look at the point to rotate towards
rotationParent.LookAt(new Vector3(
    axis == Axes.X ? rotationParent.position.x : target.transform.position.x,
    axis == Axes.Y ? rotationParent.position.y : target.transform.position.y,
    axis == Axes.Z ? rotationParent.position.z : target.transform.position.z
));

// apply offset
rotationParent.Rotate(
    axis == Axes.X ? offset : 0,
    axis == Axes.Y ? offset : 0,
    axis == Axes.Z ? offset : 0, Space.World
);

// apply constraints
if (constrainRotation)
{
    rotationParent.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
        (axis == Axes.X) ? Mathf.Clamp(UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(rotationParent).x, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0,//rotationParent.eulerAngles.x,
        (axis == Axes.Y) ? Mathf.Clamp(UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(rotationParent).y, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0,//rotationParent.eulerAngles.y,
        (axis == Axes.Z) ? Mathf.Clamp(UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(rotationParent).z, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0//rotationParent.eulerAngles.z
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code? You seem to be rotating the object 3 times

Comment: @Cyclone6664 I have added comments to help make sense of what's happening

Answer (score 0):

EulerAngles represent the rotation in degrees of an object with respect to an axis, counterclockwise.

For example, `object.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90f, 45f, 30f);` represents a rotation of 90 degrees counterclockwise on the x axis, 45 degrees counterclockwise on the y axis, and 30 degrees counterclockwise on the z axis.

So you can just get the rotation current rotation, clamp the axis you need, and assign the new angles to the object.
I didn't test it but something like this should work

```
if (constrainRotation) {
    rotationParent.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
        (axis == Axes.X) ? Mathf.Clamp(rotationParent.eulerAngles.x, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0,//rotationParent.eulerAngles.x,
        (axis == Axes.Y) ? Mathf.Clamp(rotationParent.eulerAngles.y, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0,//rotationParent.eulerAngles.y,
        (axis == Axes.Z) ? Mathf.Clamp(rotationParent.eulerAngles.z, constraintRange.x, constraintRange.y) : 0//rotationParent.eulerAngles.z
    );
}
```

Comment: probably won't ... `eulerAngles` are just **one of many** possible euler space representations of the same rotation quaternion. Unity just returns the "most human readable" one ... see [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned.`